# Debugging Python pygame being run through livewires

Tags: python, debugging, pygame, livewires

Python seems to completely ignore one of my objects - the games.Text object. Can't seem to understand why, syntax seems correct. Here's the code.

```
from livewires import games

#Creating and validating the pygame screen.
myscreen = games.Screen ()
#Loading an image into memory to create an image object
wall_image = games.load_image("wall.jpg", transparent = False)
myscreen.set_background(wall_image)
#Printing Arbitary Score
games.Text(screen = myscreen, x = 500, y = 30,
            text = "Score: 1756521",
            size = 50, color = color.black)
myscreen.mainloop()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ignore? What do you want the program to do? I'm not familiar with livewires but is games.Text an object or a method? If you're initializing an object you probably want to store it in a variable.

Comment: I'm sorry, the set_background to wall image part sets a background image of a jpg of my choosing (here wall.jpg), and the games.Text part is supposed to insert text into the (500,30) coordinate of the screen. It should print Score: 1756521, color = black.

Comment: when you say it "is supposed to" insert text, do you mean you're reading that in some documentation?

Comment: Textbook. Got it though, it was importation bugs. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be some combination of misspelling "colour" in a few places (this package is from the UK), forgetting

```
from livewires import colour
```

and failing to notice an error message:

```
NameError: name 'color' is not defined
```

At least I assume that's your problem, because after those changes it runs just fine for me, displaying the "score" text in the top right.

Comment: Haha, I was looking for logic/syntax errors. Thanks! Yes, it works now.